# Node.equals method in java.utils.HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, assignment-operator

The static class Node in Hashmap has an equals method to compare this Node object with a Node object passed as a parameter.

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;

    Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public final K getKey()        { return key; }
    public final V getValue()      { return value; }
    public final String toString() { return key + "=" + value; }

    public final int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(key) ^ Objects.hashCode(value);
    }

    public final V setValue(V newValue) {
        V oldValue = value;
        value = newValue;
        return oldValue;
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {
            Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;
            if (Objects.equals(key, e.getKey()) &&
                Objects.equals(value, e.getValue()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Have a look at the line where object o is assigned to a new Map.Entry object e.
The key and value comparison could have been done with object o itself. Why is it first copied to object e and then compared? The object o is not getting modified in any way.

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment, and I can't see a question everywhere else -> what do you have problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;` does not *assigned to a new Map.Entry object*, it only casts `o` to an `Entry` object, to be allowed to use `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods required to compare with the current `Entry` object

The only methods available on `o` are detailed here [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will type-casting in-place be more optimized then?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I don't understand what you mean sorry

Comment: I meant "(Map.Entry<?,?>)o.getKey()" but then it would typecast the key and not object o. Thanks, @arzo.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal you could do `((Map.Entry<?,?>)o).getKey()` but here as you also need the value, you would have to do it twice, for once it's ok, but when more, cast and store in a variable

Comment: Right, get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because in order to access the methods `getKey()` and `getValue()`, it needs to be cast to `Map.Entry`. That's all that line is doing.